# How to refresh a page from Windows scheduled tasks?

Tags: windows, cron, reload, at-job

we have a computer which only purpose is to display a web page on a big screen. This page has a calendar, which reloads its data every 60 seconds. The whole page reloads after 60 minutes. Both of these reloads are called from jQuery by `setInterval();` function.

This all works fine, but sometime the connection to the server is lost and then there is this message `Connection lost` shown on the big screen with some hints and a button to reload the page (on Firefox).

Is there a way, how to reload this page (or a tab in Firefox (or other browser)) with a Windows `at` command (scheduled task) automatically every X minutes? Or do you have other tips or solutions how to make sure that the page is always shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For firefox:
  use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-auto-reload/

For chrome:
  use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=en

To display a website, I think 1 of this 2 browser will do the trick.
Personally I am using firefox to display computer lab timetable in my institution.